# How to update a cookie in Django

Tags: django, cookies

In other languages, it's very easy to update for example the expire date in a cookie, but I can't for my life figure out how to do it in Django!

The reason for updating the expire date instead of setting a new cookie is so I don't have to do a database call on every page.

EDIT:
Thanks for all the answers, but it seems to be some confusion about what I'm trying to accomplish, so I'll try to be more precise:
**SETTING or GETTING a cookie is not the question**. What I would like to know is **how to UPDATE an already set cookie**.
Sorry for the misunderstanding!

Comment: I've actually not found any way to do it. I thought there would be a way to 1. Get the cookie 2. Change the expire date, simple as that. 
Pseudo code that doesn't work: 
c = request.COOKIES['mycookie']
c.expire = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=30)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

At some point, for a new user, you should set the cookie.  Cookie expire time is usually a per user case.  In Django, you can set the cookie age with the following code:

```
response = redirect('somewhere') # replace redirect with HttpResponse or render
response.set_cookie('cookie_name', 'cookie_value', max_age=1000)
```

The above cookie will expire after 1000s in a user's browser.

There's also an `expires` attribute where you can specify an expire date.

Reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponse.set_cookie

**EDIT**

From the django source code, try the following:

```
response = redirect('somewhere') # replace redirect with HttpResponse or render
response.cookies['cookie_name']['expires'] = datetime.today() + timedelta(days=1)
```

Expire the above 1 day from today.

Comment: I already set the cookie, the question is how to update an already set cookie?

Comment: I tried your edited response, but it seems that you cannot do that with the standard cookies (getting KeyError 'cookie_name', even if you previously set that cookie). After looking into this, it seems it might work if you use django.http.SimpleCookie(). I'll investigate further.. thanks for the lead!

Answer (score 3):

Accessing cookies: `request.COOKIES[..]`

Setting cookies: `response.set_cookie()`

More informations here: [django book: Sessions...](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter14/)

Comment: Is it possible to modify an accessed cookie a la request.COOKIES['mycookie'].expire = etc?

Comment: Yes look at http://justcramer.com/2007/12/20/set-cookies-without-a-response-in-django/ you can modify to change expire time

Answer (score 0):

Three ways:
1)

```
response = render_to_response(template_name, {'data':'data'})
response.set_cookie("cookie_name","test_value")
return response
```

2Midellware: http://justcramer.com/2007/12/20/set-cookies-without-a-response-in-django/

3) javascript in template

Comment: Well, I want to explore a solution that doesn't involve setting the cookie again. Could of course go the js way, but it doesn't feel very...pythonic :)

Answer (score 0):

this is how you can render a template with any context, and changing cookie

```
    context = {"any_context_key_1":"value_1", "key_2": "value_2"}
    response = render(request, 'index.html', context)
    response.set_cookie("this_is_cookies_key", "this_is_its_value", max_age=None)
    return response
```